# How to close own modal on outside click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made modal window. It closes by clicking on X button.
But now I want to close it, if user click of modal outside area.

```
    $("a[href='#modal']").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("body").addClass("noscroll");
        $(".modal").addClass("is-active");
        $(".modal_overlay").addClass("is-active");
    });
    $(".modal .close").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(".modal").hasClass("is-active")) {
            $("body").removeClass("noscroll");
            $(".modal").removeClass("is-active");
            $(".modal_overlay").removeClass("is-active");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
function close(){
    $("body").addClass("noscroll");
    $(".modal").addClass("is-active");
    $(".modal_overlay").addClass("is-active");
}
$("a[href='#modal']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    close();
});
$(".modal .close").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(".modal").hasClass("is-active")) {
        close();
    }
});
$(window).click(function(e) {
       close();
       return false;
});
$(".modal").click(function(){
    return false; // prevents a click in dialog to close the modal
});
```

It just handles the click on the window to close the modal, while intercepting them in the modal to prevent them from hitting the previous event handler.